# Iteratively built column in SQL/Power BI

Tags: sql, powerbi

Suppose I have a table A with columns - Row Number, Item_ID, ID, Quantity

I' d like to create a column (let's call it Usage) - either in SQL or directly in Power BI (with power query/ calculated columns) along the lines of the following pseudo code:

```
int i =1;
while i <= NumberOfRows(A)
{
    quantity_1 = ( select sum(usage) 
                     from A 
                    where [Row Number] < i 
                      and Item_ID = A[i,Item_ID] 
                      and ID = A[i,ID]);

    if quantity_1 is null then 
       set quantity_1 = 0 ;
    Set A[i,Usage] to SomeArithmeticsOn(A[i,Quantity]) + quantity_1;
    i++;
}
```

The A table has around 200 000 rows so it is not possible to achieve this with SQL's while loop (because it is too slow). I'd be grateful for any tips and suggestions.

Comment: Can you please post an example of your data and expected output?

Comment: DAX is even more limited than SQL with regard to iterative/recursive functionality. I don't know that this is possible unless you find a nice closed-form version of your iterative function. Might be doable in the Power Query M language, but I'm not sure that it would be faster than SQL.